# How to change the amount in a paypal subscription after the first payment?

Tags: paypal

On my site I'm using coupons which can be applied just on first payment. So in case of subscription just on the first payment the coupon should be applied. How can I specify the amount to charge after the first payment?
I'm using IPN with url parameters:

```
src= 1, srt=12, t3=M, p3=1, a3=00.1
```

according to:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HF00TZS

Comment: Offer a trial period with a different amount for the trial.

Comment: working, ty, put it as an answer and so I can check it.